# Best way to manage minutes of meeting

Tags: documentation, project-management, documentation-generation, meetings

What is the best way of managing minutes of meeting on daily bases ? Do we have to manage the documents in a repository like VSS or it can be maintained in a excel sheet itself.

Kindly share your experience for the same and guide.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is related to project-management. Our current project is updated frequently based on the Customer Requests(CR) from time to time. Each CR implementation is done after through meetings with the client for which the MOM is maintained and are referenced to in the future in case of some deviation.

Comment: @martin @hot As long as its about development meetings its on-topic.  However, this might be better suited for programmers.SE.  If OP wants me to migrate, I will.

Comment: @hot - If the key point is to avoid debate about what has been agreed with those raising the CRs, it would be best to 'close the loop' with them.  That is, get them to sign off on the minutes soon after each meeting.  That might be done simply by an exchange of email.

Answer (score 1):

Source code control is not a great location for docs in binary format, so I'd use it as a last resort.

I'd suggest setting up a wiki or some internal website. We use Sharepoint for storing and managing this kind of doc. A wiki might not integrate too well with things like an Excel spreadsheet (although maybe it could be made to work), so you may need to store docs like that on a share drive and reference them from the wiki.

Another idea for a regular meeting like this might be an internal blog to report on progress and record minutes, again referencing docs on a share if needs be.

Answer (score 0):

You should publish an agenda before the meeting and keep minutes with action items for each meeting. Part of the agenda should be to go through the action items from the previous meeting and either check them off, postpone them, or cut them if it's obvious they will never get done.

I would dump a copy of the minutes into whatever content management system you use.

Comment: The problem with going through the previous action items is that it often degenerates into explaining them *again* to people who weren't directly concerned. An alternative is to include a list of the action points with the agenda, which you can just pass round the table and each person adds a check mark to any points that have been actioned.

Comment: You don't have to go into the details of old business in detail, especially if they've been tabled to a committee. Just repeat, this point was tabled to the committee and our conclusion was X. No need to burn too much time on it.